# DialogFragment opened from Activity or Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I want to detect whether the DialogFragment is opened from an Activity or Fragment. Because the calling Activity or Fragment will have an Interface attached for a listener.

if Activity is used to show the dialog:
(inside DialogFragment I will write)

```
listener = (MyListener) getActivity();
```

else if Fragment is calling the dialog:

```
listener = (MyListener) getParentFragment;
```

So, I need to detect who is calling the dialog fragment!

Comment: pass some parameter in that interface like a boolean `isFromActivity` or something like that

Comment: Why u want to do like this?

Comment: @VivekMishra Thanks! I am using currently that way only i.e using parameters!

Comment: @LokeshDesai  I want to know because it will help me to set the listener properly. if my dialog fragment sets listener using getActivity() then if a Fragment opens the  dialog fragment then getActivity will throw an error!

Comment: whenever you are calling the dialog pass the context as parameter..it will help u in all scenarios in case of fragment pass getParentFragment and in Activity pass getActivity.

Comment: Thanks! @SyedDanishHaider

Answer (score 1):

#### If you ask me to edit your code then do this.

```
void showDialog() {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new MyAlertDialogFragment();
    newFragment.setFromActivity(true); pass here.
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
}
```

In your `DialogFragment`

```
public static class MyAlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
   boolean isFromActivity;
   public void setFromActivity(boolean isFromActivity){
    this.isFromActivity = isFromActivity;
   }
}
```

#### If you ask me a suggestion - Pass listener instead of checking from Activity or Fragment.

You should do common code by using setters, so that in future you can just pass listener.

```
DialogFragment newFragment = new MyAlertDialogFragment();
newFragment.setListener(this); // or use anonymous deriving like new Listener()...
```

Comment: Cool! Thanks. I am using like this --> MyDialog.newInstance(MyListener).

Comment: I have posted an answer, how I am using it, Just check if it is right!

Answer (score 1):

I am using the below style for my question, posting as an answer because it might help someone.

```
public MyDialog extends DialogFragment{
    private MyListener listener;

    public static MyDialog newInstance(MyListener callback){
        MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog();
        dialog.listener = callback;
        return dialog;
    }

    //rest of the Dialog code such as onCreate() etc..

}
```

**And calling from Any Activity or Fragment**

**ACTIVITY**

```
public MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyListener{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);

    MyDialog dialog = MyDialog.newInstance(this);
    dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager, "TAG");
    }

}
```

**FRAGMENT**

```
public MyFragment extends Fragment implements MyListener{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_frag_layout, container, false);

    MyDialog dialog = MyDialog.newInstance(this);
    dialog.show(getChildFragmentManager, "TAG"); 

    return view;
}

}
```

Please comment if there is any possiblity of error or conditions where it can crash. Thank you!